# ContentProvider that combines ContentProviders

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to achieve isolation and modularization, so I store data in different apps that talk to each other.

I have a custom `ContentProvider` for public "foos" called `FooContentProvider`.

A second `ContentProvider` in a second app should hold some "bar" for some of the foos based on the matching "foo_id".

A third app should now be able to display a `ListView` with all the foos and if available, also the bars.

Now I'm stuck on how to organize my code. Can I get my `FooBarContentProvider` to list foos with associated bars or should I join these only in the FooBar ListView App? How can I still leverage the databases involved without duplicating data or having to store the joined table in memory?

#### Option #1: Two `ContentProvider` joined into a `MatrixCursor` using `CursorJoiner`

I found `CursorJoiner` that I could use to fill a `MatrixCursor` which I could probably use for my FooBarContentProvider or optionally just in the FooBar ListView App to back the ListView but I would expect a considerable lag at startup and memory issues if the foos and bars get into the many hundreds or thousands (which power users will achieve) and of course it would not work nicely if the data changes and new foos arrive.

#### Option #2: Use only the `FooContentProvider` and provide the `BarContentProvider` from a precompiled `HashMap<String, Bar>`

If the FooBar ListView was backed by the `FooContentProvider`, it could  fill the "bar" data from a `Map`. This way I could reduce having to parse both `ContentProvider` prior to showing the first data to only one of them. Bars are smaller and strictly less than the foos in my case and changes to the foos are driven from a service, while the bars are mainly user input, so this would probably also be the better option for `notifyChange()` to work.

#### Option #3: Let a proxy `ContentProvider` collect the data into a merged database

A proxy `ContentProvider` could listen to the other two and provide the database I need but it would waste a lot of storage as especially the `FooContentProvider` will easily go into the hundreds of MB.

#### Option #4 ????

Is there a good option #4? How can I have a `ListView` that is backed by two `ContentProvider` in a way that all works smoothly especially at startup and changes in the data get propagated to the `ListView` quickly?

Comment: i'm confused: do "foo" and "bar" hold the same kind of data? my common sense tells me not, but you say you could merge them using a `MatrixCursor`...

Comment: Imagine the one to be `gig (gigId, startDate, endDate, location, ...)` and the other `personalGigNotes (gigId, note)`.

Comment: so make a provider that accepts those `Uri`s: `content://org.example.gig/gigs/` and `content://org.example.gig/gigs/<gig_id>/` and `content://org.example.gig/gigs/<gig_id>/notes/` first will return the `Cursor` with all the gigs, the second the detailed data of one particular gig and the last one, all the notes about that gig, and use them in `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`

Comment: of course it would require an `ExpandableListView`, not a `ListView`

Comment: `ExpandableListView` is not quite the use case here. It's more like an extra field that might be empty or not but never with more than one entry. `n:0/1`.

Comment: so use an sql join and return one Cursor

Comment: Can't join across `ContentProvider` from distinct apps. I can't deal with SQL at this point. Only with the `Cursor`s I get from the `ContentProvider`s.

Comment: ok, how many bars do you expect to exists? 100s? 1000s? more?

Comment: Telling by our current users we know some have 2000 foos but we don't know how many bars they use. Worst case would be 2000, too.

For me a big concern is also that this is supposed to be an API. Others should be able to implement their own foo- and bar-providing modules, so it should not get too hacky on the foo/bar provider side.

Comment: then return foos as a `CursorWrapper` which wraps foo `Cursor` and provides one virtual `note` field which will be filled either from a hash map (from your option #2) or some other fast data structure like `snappydb` for example

Comment: or even better return custom `CrossProcessCursorWrapper` from your `ContentProvider#query` method

Comment: BTW `MatrixCursor` is good when you have a small amount of data (like a list of suggestions from a REST service for example) a you need a `Cursor`, when your foo data is counted in `"hundreds of MB"` you will easily go into troubles, when using `CrossProcessCursorWrapper` there is no such issue since you work with small "window" and not with the whole data set